# Product of Matrices related to Bases is Identity Matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, abelian-groups

The following  excerpt is from "Algebraic number theory and Fermats last theorem by Ian Stewart, David Tall (3rd ed.) on page 28-

> An abelian group with a basis of $n$ elements is called a free abelian
> group of rank $n$. If $G$ is free abelian of rank $n$ and ${x_1, ... ,x_n}, {y_1, ... ,y_n}$ are both bases, then there exist integers
> $a_{ij}, b_{ij}$; such that $$y_i=\sum_ja_{ij}x_j,\;  x_i=\sum_jb_{ij}y_j,$$
>
> If we consider the matrices
>
> $$A=(a_{ij}), \; \;B=(b_{ij})$$
>
> it follows that $AB = I_n$, the identity matrix.

Can anyone please show how $AB = I_n$?

Comment: So $$\pmatrix{y_1\\\vdots\\y_n}=A\pmatrix{x_1\\\vdots\\x_n}?$$

Comment: I suggest you plug the formula for $x$ into the formula for $y$

Comment: @AnginaSeng Careful: the $x_i,y_i$ are vectors, not scalars.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm sure you are experienced enough in algebra to know that if $M$ is a left $R$-module then $R^n$ can be made into a left $M_n(R)$-module. (It's really just Morita equivalence....)

Comment: @AnginaSeng If that's what you meant, then your notation is a bit deceptive. Presumably, we should say something like
$$
\pmatrix{y_1\\\vdots\\y_n}=(A \otimes \operatorname{id}_G) \pmatrix{x_1\\\vdots\\x_n}
$$
but I suppose that's a matter of taste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugging the second equation into the first yields
$$
y_i = \sum_{j} a_{ij} \sum_k b_{jk} y_k = \sum_k \left(\sum_{j} a_{ij} b_{jk} \right) y_k, \quad i = 1,\dots,n.
$$
Because the $y_i$ form a basis, this implies that $\sum_{j} a_{ij} b_{jk}$ is equal to $1$ if $i=k$ and $0$ otherwise. In other words, $AB = I$, which was what we wanted.